# Crop image with X, Y coordinates in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm triying to crop an `dataURL` image with `X and Y` coordinates and `width and height.`
I don't want to resize the image. I just want to get the zone (x,y) and the width and height.
I've alerdy done this in PHP, but now I'm triying to do it in JS. Here's my actual code:

```
function resizeImage(url, width, height, x, y, callback) {
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        var sourceX = 0;
        var sourceY = 0;
        var sourceWidth = imageObj.width;
        var sourceHeight = imageObj.height;
        var destWidth = width;
        var destHeight = height;
        var destX = x;
        var destY = y;

        context.drawImage(imageObj, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);
        callback(canvas.toDataURL())
      };
      imageObj.src = url;
}
```

This function just changes the width & height, and that's not the result that it's supposes to do.

Here's my `PHP` code **(if it can be helpful to better understand me)**

```
<?php
class Cropper {
    var $x;
    var $y;
    var $dataURL;
    var $width;
    var $height;
    var $filter;
    function __construct($x, $y, $dataURL, $width, $height, $filter) {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
        $this->dataURL = $dataURL;
        $this->width = $width;
        $this->height = $height;
        $this->filter = $filter;
    }
    function setHeader() {
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
    }
    function Render() {
        $image = $this->dataURL;
        $image = substr($image, 22);
        $img = imagecreatetruecolor(340, 462);
        $org_img = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($image));
        imagecopy($img, $org_img, 0, 0, $this->x, $this->y, $this->width, $this->height);
        if($this->filter == 1) imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
        if($this->filter == 2) {
            imagefilter($img,IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
            imagefilter($img,IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE,100,50,0);
        }
        ob_start(); 
            imagepng($img);
            imagealphablending($img,true);
            $image_data = ob_get_contents(); 
        ob_end_clean(); 
        $image_data_base64 = base64_encode($image_data);
        imagedestroy($img);
        return 'data:image/png;base64,'.$image_data_base64;
    }
}
?>
```

I've also made a draw to better understand me:

[image: Picture]

**EDIT: sorry, inversed between X and Y**

So the function needs to return the yellow area
How can I do this? What's wrong in my code? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something like: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/ OR are you trying to write your own?

Comment: I'm triying to write my own. Don't want to use lib for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to preventing distortion seems to be setting the width and height of the canvas element.  I then used the desired cropped or **destination** width and height for both source and destination, and then used 0, 0 as the starting x, y coordinates for the sub-rectangle, or cropped **destination** image:

```
function resizeImage(url, width, height, x, y, callback) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imageObj = new Image();

    // set canvas dimensions

    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    imageObj.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
        callback(canvas.toDataURL());
    };

    imageObj.src = url;
}
```

**Edit**

Interesting discovery: In addition to cropping, you can use this to add padding to an image.

```
var padding = 10,
    sourceImgWidth = 150,
    sourceImgHeight = 100,
    paddedWidth = sourceImgWidth + padding * 2,
    paddedHeight = sourceImgHeight + padding * 2,
    x = -padding,
    y = -padding;

resizeImage('test.jpg', paddedWidth, paddedHeight, x, y, function (dataURL) {
    paddedImage.src = dataURL;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation for [CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) function:

> ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth,
>   dHeight);

*sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight* are parameters of the **sub-rectangle** of the source image

In your case: parameters  ***sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight***  should coincide with parameters ***dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight*** (in most simple case)
Change your `imageObj.onload` handler as shown below:

```
...
imageObj.onload = function() {
   context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, width, height, x, y, width, height);
   callback(canvas.toDataURL())
};
...
```

Comment: That won't crop the image.

Comment: @toomanyredirects, can you prove that? (did you see the jsfiddle example from https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) ?